# How to move an element around DOM tree without affecting related javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

In this case I have a  containing an iFrame that has an editor, mooEditable. I clone the element with IDs, destroy old one and insert new one where needed.

Javascript component doesn't work anymore at this stage. If there is a generic way to do this, it would be terrific if you share it.

TIA

Comment: I do not understand your situation and what you mean by "Javascript component". Can you clarify?

Comment: Most javascript UI components utilize iFrames as a 'clean room' for their components. Javascript components like google maps or various editors / painting tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could show the gist of what you do?  Specifically, what do you mean by "destroy old one"?

This uses jQuery, but you could code to the bare metal if you want:

```
var item = $('#item-id');  // item to move
var want = $('#new-div');  // container to receive it
item.remove();
want.append(item);
```

You may have trouble moving *iframes* (not sure). If so, and if you're just *swapping* two items, move the other one.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the code with equivalent functions. Compoentns still don't work after migration to other part in the dom tree. I suppose have to reinitialize components that generate iFrames. Far from ideal though.

Comment: Why are you moving it in the DOM?  If you want to move it on the page, you could try changing the CSS instead...

Comment: @james-van-dyke is correct: `remove()` will detach all events and remove all children from the container you're trying to move. But no need to use `clone()`: jQuery provides a simple method called `detach()` that works just the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

i would think the correct way to move an item in mootools is this:

```
$("newparent").adopt($("movingThis"));
```

otherwise, any events etc may not work. you can also use cloneEvents() if you have to save/reapply them, but should not have to. also, this is the only way that is guaranteed to keep all relations between the element and other javascript, as well as retain any element storage you may have had.

regards,
coda

Comment: Best answer for MooTools. Also, `adopt` is some very nice function naming - just that one word explains it all.

Answer (score 2):

You're losing the events and behaviors associated with the elements.   Try using the [.clone method](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:clone) if you're not already.  Read the documentation for it and be aware of the cloneEvents() function and the keepid parameter.

```
var myOrigEditor = $('myEditor');

//clone the element and its events
var myClonedEditor = myOrigEditor.clone(true, true).cloneEvents(myOrigEditor); 

// We're copying IDs as well, so remove the old one from the DOM first to
// remove any possibility of confusion.
myOrigEditor.remove();

// Put the cloned object where you want.
$('location').append(myClonedEditor);
```